# I cannot install "unifdef" on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, software-installation

After I ran `yum install unifdef`

I got "No package unifdef available"

I already added all sources.

(Base, contrib, Debuginfo, Extras,  Plus and Updates)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`unifdef` is not packaged in the CentOS 6 repositories. You need to either install it using a third-party package from a third-party repository, or compile it from source.

Comment: thanks Chris. I have installed by compiling from sourcecode